# Impulse response of system with $\max\left\{\lvert x[n] \rvert\right\}\ge\max\left\{\lvert y[n]\rvert \right\}$

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

> Find a relation/condition for the impulse response, so for any $x[n]$ (input) with $y[n]$ (output) this relation is true:
> $$ \max\left\{\lvert x[n] \rvert\right\} \ge \max\left\{\lvert y[n]\rvert \right\}$$
> The system is discrete, linear and time invariant.

I tried to replace the $y[n]$ with the convolution formula,but it doesn't work. I tried to use Fourier transformation, but it doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! I added a few line breaks and the `>` citation marker to make your question easier to read. Welcome here!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly the question is: find some LTI system that meets this constraint (which is trivial) or create a testable condition for any LTI system. (Which is not trivial).

For the latter: Discrete LTI systems are guaranteed to not increase the maximum amplitude if the absolute sum of the impulse response is smaller than $1$, i.e.

$$\sum |h(n)| \leq 1 $$

The proof is a bit tedious, so I'll skip it unless there is need for it.

Comment: The question is to create a testable condition for any LTI system.I think that the sum you wrote above is too close to the solution,can you give me a link with the proof?

Answer (score 2):

To simplify notations (and, honestly, put convergence troubles aside), let us consider a finite impulse response system. Every output then becomes, in a sliding way, an weighted average of  samples $x[k]$: $y[\cdot] =\sum_k a_kx[k]$. Easily, you get:

$$|y[\cdot]| =\left|\sum_k a_kx[k]\right|\le \sum_k |a_k||x[k]|\le \max |x[k]|\sum_k |a_k|$$

So $\max |y[k]|$ is smaller than  $\max |x[k]|$ when $\sum_k |a_k|\le 1$. If $\sum_k |a_k|= 1$, choose $x[k] = \textrm{sign}\, a_k$, to see that the bound is tight. This could be a testable starting point.

In a nutshell: as long as $\sum_k |a_k|\le 1$, the condition is satisfied. And you can design an input signal with a subsequence of values, defined by the signs of the flipped impulse response, to attain the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. The literally simplest possible linear system (that's not output=input) can do this for you, if you're using the right parameter.

Another solution (which is a special case of the recommended system above) is also

$$y[n] = 0\text.$$

Comment: Yes,but i think that i must find a solution,that has impulse response in it.ex h[n]>2x[n] Is this relation true for every system?(max{|x[n]|}≥max{|y[n]|})

Comment: $h[n] = 2x[n]$ is not an impulse response of a time-invariant system. Get your technical terms right! I think what you mean is right, but the way you say it isn't. Also, you can easily test your hypothesis yourself. Not doing your homework!

Comment: Its August,i don't have any homework,Im trying to prepare myself for some exams and im stuck with this problem.The ex h[n]>2x[n] was an example so people can understand my question.It was not a possible solution.So dont blame me that i want you to solve my "homework".Thank you for your time.

Comment: but that's the problem: your $h[n]$ is **not** an example of an impulse response of a linear time invariant system. And with "doing your homework" I meant: doing the checking that you can do you yourself very well.

Comment: Now i understand your statement,yep h[n]>2x[n] was technically wrong,maybe  ∑|h(n)|≤1 is a more appropriate example for the kind of solution im looking for.

Comment: ... Really, re-read my answer. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

this is i believe what you were looking for

https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw05_sol.pdf

[image: https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw05_sol.pdf]